# asp.net form output: streamwriter to write to file versus database connection

Tags: asp.net, database, forms, csv, streamwriter

I have to make an ASP.net form and only need to gather 3 fields: name, bday and email.

Do you think it's best to write the info to a csv or xml file, or do you think it's worth it to write to a SQL DB or something and then export from there to a file?

I'm of the opinion that just writing to a flat file is best because it's just going to need to be exported into a csv/xml file anyway so it can be appended to an excel file.

I'd use something like streamwriter or filestream in my C# submitbutton function:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename, true);
sw.WriteLine(string.Concat
( textBox1.Text
, textBox2.Text
, textBox3.Text
, textBox4.Text
, textBox5.Text
, textBox6.Text
, textBox7.Text ));
sw.Close();
```

Am I overlooking shortcomings of using csv and StreamWriter? Like do any weird things happen when the file gets to a certain size?

Also, how is Streamwriter compared to Filestream, or should I be looking at a different method entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for small applications you will never regret using a database. Especially if they ever change / grow. Text files are a lot harder to make a change if you want to store other data.

File access for web applications be challenging at best. If you do use a Database I would ultimately look in to XML/XSD and using Data Sets.